# How to check if the current time falls within specific range with selenium IDE?

Tags: if-statement, selenium-ide

I need to check if the current time is within 6:00 and 18:00. How to use if in this situation? I get the current time in format hhmi

```
var d= new Date(); 
var h=((d.getHours())<10)?'0'+(d.getHours()):(d.getHours()); 
var n=((d.getMinutes())<10)?'0'+(d.getMinutes()):(d.getMinutes());
' '+h+n;
```

and need to do something like this in selenium IDE:

if 600 < ${currentTime} < 1800

do something;

else

do something;

Answer (score 0):

In selenium IDE there is no native looping or conditional branching like this. There are plug ins for that though.

Otherwise, you could try keeping it just in javascript to make your decision making. I'd need to know more about what you're trying to do to see if that helps.